# Running TS Lint on legacy angular project

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

When I'm trying to lint my angular legacy app via VS Code TsLint extension (runtime linting), unfortunately extension fails.

At startup we have following version set:

```
"@angular/cli": "~1.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
"autoprefixer": "^6.5.1",
"codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
"jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
"karma": "1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"protractor": "4.0.5",
"ts-node": "1.2.1",
"tslint": "3.13.0",
"typescript": "2.2.2"
```

This setup is able to run `ng lint`, but VS Code Tslinter extensions fails with following:

`vscode-tslint: Cannot read tslint configuration - 'Cannot read property 'findConfigurationPath' of undefined'`

I've been going through some github discussion on that, but it was related with way older version of extension. I'm currently using 1.0.38.

Does anyone else have similar issues? I'm almost 100% sure that this issue is related with mixing old versions of project tools with new VS Code extensions...

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran to same issue today and it seems like dependencies for vscode-tslint have been updated.

I had to upgrade to:

```
"tslint": "^5.7.0",
"typescript": "^2.9.1"
```

To get it working.

I presume the current requirements can be seen [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/blob/master/package.json).

Comment: Yes, indeed this was a version conflict. Beside updating local versions I purged global installations, restart VS Code couple times ;) and suddenly it all went up and running